I can't see the maze?
> CANYOUTRYTO
  MAKEITTHROUGH
  THEMAZE
  FROMBEGINNING
  TOENDINA
  LOGICAL
  MANNERBUT
  TOWALKONLY
  ONPATHS?HAVE
  AFUNTIMEAND
  BEQUICK!
  ALSOYOUWILL
  HAVETOCROSS38
  LETTERSOR
  NUMBERS.
  WHATARETHEY? (8, 16, 2, 11, 14, 18, 37)
      V      

The final answer to the question is a word.

Anyone have a guess so far?

@webadventurer: I have an idea that kinda works, but I can't find the final answer. (I assume that the numbers in parentheses are indices into the path through the "maze". And I'm not sure how my approach is "logical".)

@M Oehm I am not sure if you meant this or not but I thought the numbers are just to be used for extracting a word from the 38 letters/numbers passed over. There is a correspondence between the numbers and the letters based on ‘distance’ from the start.

I guess the ‘paths’ are referring to the fact that only orthogonal routes are allowed. But this is as far as I got, I have not idea how to make a path that is logical either. My initial thought was finding a sequence of words/names through the maze but to no avail!

Wow. A moment of inspiration just now and it amazingly (no pun intended but I'm leaving it in now I've spotted it) all fell into place. Fun idea, nicely delivered! :)

@PDT: Yes, I meant just that. (But my idea was nowhere near the actual answer.)

This is a lovely puzzle! There's a very good reason you can't see this maze...

 It's written in Braille, the tactile alphabet system of raised dots used by the blind!



 The title is the main hint towards this.

So let's take the letters given...

 ...and plot them out in a grid, giving each of them a 2x3 space which we will shortly populate with the required dots for their Braille representations...



 ...then let's pump this thing full of dots!



Now when we try to solve the maze, we can clearly see the path!

 

 Any possible deviations can be resolved by considering the stipulation that only 38 letters are passed through (and the route through the first 2 letters where there is plenty of space is flexible).

So let's look at the letters we passed through...

 Click on the image below to see it all in its intended resolution.


 As a string these spell out 'CAAKEIABEGIANLBRKLENAAPUFABELAHLEUMBEA', which is meaningless by itself. However, if we then look at the 8th, 16th, 2nd, 11th, 14th, 18th and 37th letters in this string as suggested by the numbers in parentheses in the puzzle...

 C[A]AKEIA[B]EG[I]AN[L]B[R]K[L]ENAAPUFABELAHLEUMB[E]A

 ...then read in that order, these spell out the self-confirmatory phrase BRAILLE!

Great puzzle, difficult to solve, but once you see your way into the maze, you can feel your way out of it!

Wow crazy solution! Would have never guessed this in a million years!

Ha! Very good. (And not at all what I thought of.)

@PDT Ha, thanks :) When I tentatively began converting the first 3 rows of letters I wondered if this was going to be a very long, mad, pointless diversion... but then I started to see walls and narrow gaps leading through them which made me wonder if I was onto something. When I began shading the red path I kept saying out loud "Surely not, no, no way... NO. WAY..." - but as it turned out: 'way'.
